# How to add a note on UIwebview

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiwebview, uimenucontroller

I would like to implement a function like adding a note of a selected text on `UIWebview` as iBooks and Amazon Kindle does.

I already created `UIMenuItem`. But, I dont know how to implement the method for this. Could anybody help in this regard?

I dont know what functionality is used to implement in this method. Thanks.

```
- (void)Note:(id)sender {
    NSString *selection = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"]; 
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get something working for this?

Comment: sir, i also need the same problem,were u get any answer means kindly post it

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript in question is designed to give you the text that is highlighted within your selection.

I'm not sure that running toString on an element will return the correct information though.  The following method will return the highlighted text and save it into a variable.

```
function getHighlightedString() {
    var text        = window.getSelection();
    myAnchorOffset = text.anchorOffset;
    myFocusOffset = text.focusOffset;
    myHighlightLength=myFocusOffset-myAnchorOffset;
    if(myHighlightLength<0)
    {
        myHighlightLength*=-1;
        temp = myAnchorOffset;
        myAnchorOffset = myFocusOffset;
        myFocusOffset = temp;

    }


    selectedText    = text.anchorNode.textContent.substr(myAnchorOffset, myFocusOffset - myAnchorOffset);



}
```

when you have this method loaded into the webview

```
NSString myHighlightedText = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getHighlightedString()"];
```